# Parallel/Offset 3D curve

Tags: curves

I'm trying to understand the logic (theory?) behind the offset/parallel curve for the design of a radial diffuser.

I found the equations for a 2D parametrical offset curve on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve#Parallel_curve_of_a_parametricaly_given_curve), where the normal unit vector to the original curve is defined as the first derivative of the original curve.

However, [in this article](https://math.libretexts.org/TextMaps/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Vector_Calculus/2%3A_Vector-Valued_Functions_and_Motion_in_Space/2.3%3A_Curvature_and_Normal_Vectors_of_a_Curve) , the normal vector is defined as a second drivative of the original curve.

What I'm trying to achieve is: I would like to define the equation of the offset curve and then play around a little bit to make it "progressive" compared to the original curve.

My original curve is:

$a_3=11.482$

$b_3=-10.629$

$c_3=0$

$r_3=81.109$

$x=r_3\cos(t)+a_3$

$y=r_3\sin(t)+b_3$

$z=5t(20^t)+c_3$

Edit: the offset of the curve is in the z direction

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: In the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case the offset curve has not a precise meaning unless this curve is onto a surface and the offset to the curve is taken on this surface.

Comment: I should be more precise, the offset of the curve is in the direction of the z component. I will update the OP.

Comment: after some google-fuing, I found this:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221434073_Directional_Offset_of_a_Spatial_Curve_for_Practical_Engineering_Design

Comment: the paper from the link in the comment above describes the my problem perfectly, but the equation they provide ( r_d(t) = r(t) + d*n(t) ), just doesn't deliver the desired offset curve to my original curve.